# Show that a subset of $\mathbb R$ with some properties is a field

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

$F \subset \mathbb R, 1 \in F$ and $F \ne \{0,1\}$, $\forall a,b \in F, a \ne 0, \frac{1}{a} - b \in F$. We need to show that $F$ is a field.

It is easy to see that:

1. $0 \in F$ because $1 \in F$ and $\frac{1}{1} - 1 = 0$.
2. $a \ne 0 \in F \implies \frac{1}{a} \in F$ (set $b=0$ in $\frac{1}{a} - b$).

and here I am stuck, not sure how to show that:

1. $a \in F \implies -a \in F$
2. $a,b \in F \implies a+b, ab \in F$

**Edit**

Using the help from  Hetebrij we can show further things:

3. $-1 \in F$
4. $a \in F \implies -a \in F$, indeed, if $a=0$, then $-a = 0 \in F$, if $a \ne 0$, then $\frac{1}{a} \in F$ and $\frac{1}{\frac{1}{a}} - (-1)= a+ 1 \in F$ it means that $\frac{1}{1}-(a+1)=1-a-1 = -a \in F$.
5. $a,b \in F \implies a+b \in F$, indeed if $b \in F$ , then $-b \in F$, now if $a = 0$, then $a+b=b \in F$ and if $a \ne 0$, then $a - (-b) = a+b \in F$.

Comment: There is at least one $x\in F$ different from $0$ and $1$. I suggest you start playing around a bit to see what else you can get by combining things known to be in $F$ using the given formula. You'll probably stumble upon something useful. Without such play, you get nowhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let’s show that $ab\in F$ provided that $a,b\in F$; I will assume everything you have already shown. Let $a\in F\setminus\{0,1\}$. Then
$$
a-a^2 = \frac{a(1-a)}{a+1-a} = \frac1{\frac1a+\frac1{1-a}}\in F.
$$
We conclude $a^2\in F$ whenever $a\in F$ (the cases $a=0$ and $a=1$ being trivial). Obviously, we have $2a = a+a\in F$ for $a\in F$. Hence also $\frac a2 = \frac1{2a^{-1}}\in F$ for all $a\in F$ (the case $a=0$ being trivial).

Finally, for $a,b\in F$, we calculate
$$
ab = \frac12\cdot \left((a+b)^2-a^2-b^2\right) \in F.
$$

Answer (score 2):

To get you started on the remaining two points, I shall show that $-1 \in F$.
Since $F \neq \{0,1\}$, let $a \in F\backslash\{0,1\}$, then we have $0 \neq a-1 =\frac{1}{\frac{1}{a}} - 1\in F$.
Furthermore, we have $\frac{a-1}{a} = \frac{1}{1} - \frac{1}{a} \in F$. So we have 
$\frac{a}{a-1} \in F$ and thus
$$\frac{1}{a-1} - \frac{a}{a-1} = \frac{1-a}{a-1} = -1 \in F.$$

Comment: Your help took my relatively far. I see now that $\mathbb Q \subset F$. Now it would be nice to show that $\mathbb Q = F$, but not sure how and whether it is the correct direction at all.

Comment: @SergeyZykov  Well, since we now nothing about $a$, it might be that $a = \pi$, so it is impossible to show $F= \mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: I guess I need another nudge, not sure what to do with fact that F includes all rational numbers.

Comment: Can you show that $-a$ and $a+b$ are in $F$ for all $a.b \in F$?

Comment: @Heterbij Yes I can, please see an edit to the original question.I am now stuck with the last step, i.e. $a,b \in F \implies ab \in F$.